# In phone landscape, show more text per line, not just bigger text

Tags: css, mobile

I want my webpage to show less text per line if the screen is small. This way the text is not too small to read. I handle it like so:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"> // in head

#mydiv{width:100%, max-width:1000px;font-size:15px} // style

<div id = "mydiv">
  long text here
</div>
```

This works fine on a monitor screen when I increase and decrease the screen size. It also works fine in iPhone portrait mode. However, when I switch to landscape mode it doesn't expand the width - it shows the same amount of text per line, just a lot bigger. I was expecting the text size to stay the same and then show more text. I have only tried on the iPhone.

Is there a way to do that? (I don't have a smartphone myself, but this would be normal behavior, right?)

Edit: Tried adding both of these

```
-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; 
-webkit-text-size-adjust: none;
```

Same issue.

Comment: U need to put maximum-scale to 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this answer and it works. Not sure if all are necessary.

```
<meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="True">
<meta name="MobileOptimized" content="320">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">


html{ -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;} //style
```

It still allows zoom. If you also add

```
maximum-scale=1.0
```

then it does not allow zoom.

Answer (score 0):

So, if you want to specify the font-size for landscape orientation, I think you can use one of the following things and manipulate with them:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (orientation: landscape)"
href="landscape-screen.css" />
```

or

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0,maximum-scale=1" />
```

or

```
@media all and (orientation:landscape) { … }
```

or something like that.

For details: [W3C Media Queries](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/)

Answer (score 0):

A typical mobile-optimized site contains something like the following:

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">`

[view for more detail](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag)